# Angular/Typescript Referencing parent scope when current scope changes

Tags: angularjs, typescript, dropzone.js

I've written an angular controller that uses a dropzone directive to drop a file on the form. I've added an event inside my controller that fires when the file has been uploaded via dropzone which works. However, I need to set the file to a variable defined in the main controller but the scope has changed so the variable is not defined. Here's the basics of the code

```
module WU_TombstonesAdmin.controllers {
    export class tombstonesEditController {
        tombstoneId: number;
        tombstone: ITombstone;
        svc: WU_TombstonesAdmin.core.interfaces.ITombstonesAdminService;

        static $inject = ['WU_TombstonesAdmin.core.services.TombstoneService',
            '$routeParams', '$location'];

        constructor(fs: WU_TombstonesAdmin.core.services.TombstoneService,
            private $routeParams,
            private $location) {

            this.svc = fs;

            if ($routeParams.ID) {
                this.tombstoneId = $routeParams.ID;
            }
            if (this.tombstoneId == -1) {
                this.initializeTombstone();
                this.isAdding = true;
            } else {
                this.isAdding = false;
                this.getTombstone();
            }
        }

        fileUploadComplete = (file: any) => {
            console.log(file.name);
            //I need to set the tombstone.file to this uploaded file
            //but the root tombstone file doesn't exists since the 
            //context is now the dropzone context/
        }
    }
}
```

So, any ideas on how to set a root "tombstone" from that fileUploadComplete event?

**Update**

I ended up not using the dropzone directive and just explicitly setting up dropzone and adding an onComplete event to a regular javascript function that gets the scope of the module, sets the filename to the file and then applies the scope.

I still can't figure out how to access the $rootScope from within the event inside my controller ... I'd really prefer to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

> any ideas on how to set a root "tombstone" from that fileUploadComplete event?

There are lots of ways you can do this. One would be to use `tomsbtone` on `$rootScope` and have that injected into the MainController as well as into your directive.

Docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

---

Minor tip: You will probably need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` in the fileUpload to trigger an angular digest.

Comment: I tried to use $rootScope but I can't figure out how to reference it from the fileUploadComplete method. It's undefined. I tried to set a root var in the main controller and set it to $rootScope in the constructor, but that still presents the same issue in not being able to get it from this other method.